# Install Windows 10 on a Linux Machine

Tags: windows, windows-installation

I haven't use Windows since about 10 years ago, now because of work I need to install it. The problem is I don't know where to install it to in LEGACY BIOS mode. Here's my drives:

- /dev/sda: a 2TB HDD (my data disc)
- /dev/sdb: a 500MB SSD (my main OS using Linux Mint), this my /boot partition
- /dev/sdc: a 1 TB (divided into 3 partition):

  - /dev/sdc1: 300 GB (my other OS, Xubuntu)
  - /dev/sdc2: 300 GB (empty)
  - /dev/sdc3: 300 GB (empty)

Is it possible to install Windows to /dev/sdc2 or /dev/sdc3?

Comment: Not to sidestep your question, but wouldn't VirtualBox be a WAY EASIER option?  This would also let you use your familiar utilities and everything else without a reboot.. just a suggestion.  I get VERY GOOD performance running Windows on Linux or Linux on Windows.  Otherwise.. it's a PITA to put windows on an existing linux setup.. way harder than the other way around.